# How can I remove the elevation (box shadow) from a material-ui AppBar over one small section?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm trying to get rid of the elevation shadow of the navbar over the sidebar.

[image]

I'm using Material-UI's AppBar for my NavBar component.

```
export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="fixed" elevation={4}>
        <Toolbar variant="regular">
          <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using a custom sidebar component,

```
.sidebar {
  left: 0;
  top: 64px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #3f50b5;
  position: fixed;
}

.sidebar::before{
  display: none;
}
```

I don't want to lose the elevation/shadow of the entire NavBar, just the section on the left where it's over the Sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add a [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element to your `navbar` to do the job. This element would have the width of your sidebar, and would be have a `top` property accordingly to your `navbar`.

Given the `AppBar` itself has some different breakpoints you would need to change `top` accordingly:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "&::after": {
      position: "absolute",
      content: '""',
      width: "70px",
      height: "8px",
      top: "48px",
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
        top: "56px"
      },
      "@media (orientation: landscape)": {
        top: "48px"
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        top: "64px"
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function NavBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar classes={{ root: classes.root }} position="fixed" elevation={4}>
        <Toolbar variant="regular">
          <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a sandbox with only the navbar, and a darker shadow to enhance contrast:

[image: my-description]

Answer (score 14):

Adding this because I spent a lot of timing finding a simple answer to removing the elevation.

The simplest way to remove the shadow is by adding `elevation` prop to the `AppBar`.

`<AppBar position="fixed" elevation={0}>`

Comment: Simple and effective. Used this to remove Card border and drop shadow

Comment: This removes the shadow from the entire AppBar, not just the small section on the left.